# How to start with blank text boxes when the form loads

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a unit converter written in Visual Basic, using Visual Studio 2012. My frmMain_Load event handler is posted below. I am using text boxes, and combo boxes. I have textchanged, and SelectedIndexChanged events set up for both sides of the converter. My problem is that when the form loads it triggers these events, therefore, causing the program to convert empty strings that returns a zero in the text box at the start of the program. I would rather have blank text boxes. Any help or opinions would be greatly appreciated on this matter. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Show()                       ' Creates the onscreen controls so the focus can be set
    PopCombo()                      ' This procedure populates the combo boxes
    cboUnitType.SelectedIndex = 0   ' Sets the default selection on the main combo box
    txtUnit1.Focus()                ' Sets the focus on the first text box
End Sub
```

Comment: An option... After your txtUnit1.focus you can call a method that sets the fields you need blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `SelectedIndexChanged`, you should use `SelectionChangeCommitted` in order to respond **only** if the user is really the one who changed the selections.

And about the textbox event, I would go with Mr. CoDeXeR's option.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that bit of education. I learn something new everyday. I am really enjoying this website. It is full of intelligent people. I had been using textChanged events all along, and it had became a problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Would the textChanged events be best for text boxes, or is there a better approach to that as well?

Comment: @Zack AFAIK, there is no straight-forward alternative event for textChanged for textboxes unlike in ComboBoxes. Personally, I found myself using the LostFocus event. But if you really want to, there is what they call `Control.IsHandleCreated` property in handling that. But it requires some knowledge in event handling and may not be feasible in your problem.